# Stack builder is not responding

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Whenever I tried to download postGIS from stack builder, Stack builder is not responding and freeze . I do not know what I should do now. All I want to know if there is any other way to download postGIS .

Comment: What operating system are you using? You can download and install postgis separately - files and instructions are on their website: https://postgis.net/install/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even I faced the same problem. So I did this, after clicking on the download postGIS extension in the stack builder GUI, I just left my laptop untouched for a while. I closed all applications and waited for a response on the stack builder GUI. After waiting for 3-5 mins, the stuck GUI worked alright. The download was complete and the installation was successful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i tried with two versions of postgres then i read the text below in the stack builder and it leads to a link where you can dowload the postgis version you need without stack builder: https://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/

Answer (score 0):

I changed my internet with the much faster speed and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the downlaod path the stackbuilder proposes.

It proposes `c:\users\youruser`, i change it to `c:\users\youruser\downloads` (by choosing my download folder from the folder selector popup)
and it immediately worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows10 Pro and Familly, with Postgres 12 (Community).
Turns out that the latest version didn't work/freeze: v3.3.2 but the previous one did v3.2.3

(Using StackBuilder 4.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what others have said, when using Stack Builder 4.2.1, I waited no less than 23 mins, got a warning, clicked to proceed, waited 10 more minutes, got frustrated for it not responding and it did not respond.

[Photo of Stack Builder's Warning due to certificate error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laGfF.png)

I suggest you guys to just follow Angel Geovanni P. Carretero' answer. I downloaded the PostGIS for pg16 and it worked.