# Couldn't access to URL https://www.postgresql.org/applications-v2.xml

Tags: postgresql

I'm on Windows 11, I was installing postgresql 15.4, when it finishes the installation and opens the stack builder 4.1.2, I get the error: Couldn't access to URL https://www.postgresql.org/applications-v2.xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OckB.png)

I have verified that my internet connection is active and that I can access other websites without problems, and I have access to the url https://www.postgresql.org/applications-v2.xml .

My computer is not configured to use a proxy server.

My expectation was to use Stack Builder to customize my PostgreSQL installation with additional components, and I'm interested in resolving this bug so I can take advantage of all the capabilities PostgreSQL offers in my project.

Comment: Check out this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/555125/postgresql-stack-builder-installation-proxy-setting-on-windows) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963158/stack-builder-is-not-responding).

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work for me